# Copy vector <char> to 2d vector <string> c++

Tags: c++, vector, stl, lambda

Is there an easy way to copy a vector char to a position in a 2d vector string while leaving the 2d vector as a member variable?

For example:

I want to copy the buffer into data[0][0]

```
class foo
{
private:
    vector<vector<string>> data;
};
```

in source somewhere

```
vector<char> buffer = {copyMe}
```

Comment: why do you want to copy to vector<char> not vector<string>, these are different types

Comment: Copy how? Please provide an example of the input and desired output.

Comment: It is not a 2D vector. It is a vector of vectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <algorithm> // std::copy
#include <iterator>  // std::back_inserter

std::copy(buffer.begin(), buffer.end(), std::back_inserter(data[0][0]));
```

This appends the contents of `buffer` to the string at `data[0][0]`.

Comment: OP wants an opposite actually

Comment: @lizusek For me its hard to tell what the OP actually wants

Comment: Well, OP says: "I want to copy the buffer into data[0][0]". My code does something like that... :-)

Comment: yes, and showed vector<char> buffer = {copyMe}, nevertheless this won't compile

Comment: I think this will work, but I get a vector subscript out of range error.

Comment: @resolv You get the error because your `data` vector or `data[0]` vector is empty. You have to initialize `data` and then `data[0]` to have at least one item in order to be able to access `data[0][0]`. For example: `data.push_back(std::vector<string>()); data[0].push_back(""); buffer.push_back('x'); buffer.push_back('y');`

Answer (score 0):

Basically we can just copy vector into another using `memcpy` if these vectors are of same type

```
std::vector<char> vc;
//...
std::vector<char> vs;
vs.resize( vc.size());
memcpy( &vs[0], &vc[0], vs.size());
```

or

```
std::copy( vc.begin(), vc.end(), vs.begin());
```

but here because of different types `char` and `std::string` casting won't work. We can do a copy in loop, element by element, this way:

```
std::vector<char> vc;
//...
std::vector<std::string> vs;
for ( size_t i = 0; i < vc.size(); i++) {
  vs.push_back( std::string(&vc[i], &vc[i+1]));
}
```

Comment: I have tried the second option, but it throws vector subscript out of range. I must be missing something.

Comment: @resolv do you mean copy element by element?